# Cannot install MediaWiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-installation

I am install MediaWiki 1.26.0 and facing this error.

*Install*
**Setting up database... done
Creating tables...**

> A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the
>   software.

**Query:**

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX user_name ON `wkuser` (user_name)
Function: DatabaseBase::sourceFile( /var/www/html/mw/maintenance/tables.sql )
Error: 1031 Table storage engine for 'wkuser' doesn't have this option (localhost)
```

> 0 /var/www/html/mw/includes/db/Database.php(1076): DatabaseBase->reportQueryError('Table storage e...', 1031, 'CREATE
>   UNIQUE I...', 'DatabaseBase::s...', false)
>   1 /var/www/html/mw/includes/db/Database.php(3979): DatabaseBase->query('CREATE UNIQUE I...', 'DatabaseBase::s...')
>   2 /var/www/html/mw/includes/db/Database.php(3893): DatabaseBase->sourceStream(Resource id #127, false, false,
>   'DatabaseBase::s...', false)
>   3 /var/www/html/mw/includes/installer/DatabaseInstaller.php(196): DatabaseBase->sourceFile('/var/www/html/m...')
>   4 /var/www/html/mw/includes/installer/DatabaseInstaller.php(218): DatabaseInstaller->stepApplySourceFile('getSchemaPath', 'install',
>   true)
>   5 [internal function]: DatabaseInstaller->createTables(Object(MysqlInstaller))
>   6 /var/www/html/mw/includes/installer/Installer.php(1592): call_user_func(Array, Object(MysqlInstaller))
>   7 /var/www/html/mw/includes/installer/WebInstallerPage.php(1419): Installer->performInstallation(Array, Array)
>   8 /var/www/html/mw/includes/installer/WebInstaller.php(280): WebInstallerInstall->execute()
>   9 /var/www/html/mw/mw-config/index.php(77): WebInstaller->execute(Array)
>   10 /var/www/html/mw/mw-config/index.php(36): wfInstallerMain()
>   11 {main}

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I have ot select **MyISAM**  instead of **InnoDB**.

And I could get it installed properly.